# while loop running forever in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Following is my code, in which I am trying to reduce the size of each array item by 2 and once the particular value of an array becomes `0` or `-1` I will replace it with `undefined`.

Example -

**Input** - `[5,4,4,2,2,8]`

**Output** -

```
Array            Non Blank Values    
5 4 4 2 2 8          6        
3 2 2 _ _ 6          4        
1 _ _ _ _ 4          2        
_ _ _ _ _ 3          1        
_ _ _ _ _ _        DONE
```

Code (Somehow its going as an infinite loop)-

```
var arr = [5,4,4,2,2,8]; // 6 4 2 1
var num = 0;
itemNum = countItemNotUndefined(arr);

function makeItemUndefine(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(x){
        x = x - 2;
        return x ==0 || x == -1 ? undefined : x;
    })
}

function countItemNotUndefined(arr) {
    var itemLength = 0;
    arr.map(function(x){
        if(x !== undefined)
            itemLength++;   
    })
    return itemLength;
}

while(itemNum != 0) {
    num ++;
    var result = makeItemUndefine(arr);
    itemNum = countItemNotUndefined(result);
}

console.log("Number is ", num);
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: why wouldn't it run forever? `itemNum` never changes

Comment: @vsync I am trying to reduce the `itemNum` to `zero` by passing the result in `countItemNotUndefined(arr)`

Comment: It looks like result is reset to the original array every time it loops rather than using the modified array from the previous loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `makeItemUndefine` on `arr`, which doesn't change, since you assign the result to a different variable called `result`.  So you aren't actually reducing the numbers in the array over time.

The correct solution would be:

```
while(itemNum != 0) {
    num ++;
    arr = makeItemUndefine(arr);
    itemNum = countItemNotUndefined(arr);
}
```

Another problem with the code is the fact that you're trying to subtract from undefined numbers, which turns them, into `NaN`'s.  There are two solutions to this, either check for `NaN` inside of `countItemNotUndefined`, or check for `undefined` inside of the map.